# Returning a ruby variable into Rails.root.join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization

So I'm currently localising a rails app, i'm currently loading only one locale file in a function, though i'm wondering how I could go about storing the currently active locale in a variable and adding that instead of the basic 'en.yml'. Here's my current code:

```
yml ||= YAML.load_file(::Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'en.yml'))
@permissions_list ||= yml['en']['permissions']
```

I've tried:

```
yml ||= YAML.load_file(::Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'I18n.locale'))
```

but with no luck

Comment: It looks like you are loading a "permission list" from your locale file? Is this a translatable text or something else?

Comment: @pascalbetz yes it is a permissions list, is there a better way to localise my permissions list (just the actual text as this is shown on our user roles page) without putting it into my locale files? i moved it from a seperate config file into my locale, i'm a bit up in the air about it

Comment: Is this permission list just text or is it something more. locale files are usually just for translatable text. They have a predefined structure (first key is the locale) and are loaded automatically. And can be accessed through `I18n.t`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to.

Rails will automatically load the files for the current locale. If the locale for example is `de` rails will load:

```
config/locales/de.yml
```

You can get it to load from nested folders by changing `config.i18n.load_path`. See [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

But to answer your original question you can construct a dynamic string in Ruby by:

```
I18n.locale + ".yml" 
# or
"#{I18n.locale}.yml"
# or about 100 other ways
```

Comment: As suggested by @max, try to use Rails default way of loading locales instead of using your own.